# How to serialize model (built from xsd.exe) to XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, stream, xmldocument

Looking at the following code, I am trying to see how I can offer XmlDocument from the xsd.exe generated object model:

```
var myModelObj = new MyModel();
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmlStr = null;
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Models.MyModel));
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myModelObj);
    xmlWriter.Flush();
    // xmlDoc = ______________ ????
    xmlStr = sw.ToString();
}
```

The intention is to service in-memory store with xml (XmlDocument?) that I can eventually use to produce an encrypted stream or file output.  Thanks!

Update:

Would this work?

```
xmlDoc.Load(sw.ToString());
```

Is there a way to produce XmlDocument output more directly from the XmlSerializer's Serialize method?

Comment: You could use `XmlNodeExtensions.SerializeToXmlDocument()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29307126/3744182) to [How to create sets of the serialized objects C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29297181/3744182).

Comment: Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548808/3744182) and [this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569122/3744182) to [How to create an XML document from a .NET object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2548708/3744182), which are the better answers despite not being accepted, and show how to directly create an `XmlDocument` via serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297181/how-to-create-sets-of-the-serialized-objects-c-sharp/29307126#29307126) by dbc, I create extension:

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument<T>(this T o)
    {
        return SerializeToXmlDocument(o, new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()));
    }

    public static XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument<T>(this T o, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
            serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

And implement like:

```
var xmlDoc = myModelObj.SerializeToXmlDocument(
    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(
        typeof(Models.MyModel)
        )
    );
```